# How do I check if category matches in R where the category is stored in a different file and an element can have multiple categories?

Tags: r, match, categories

I have two tables, Catdata and ElementData. I want `ElementData$Match` to return 1 if `Catdata$category` is `fiction` or `suspense` or `thriller` and 0 otherwise. How would I do this without looping?

Catdata

```
Element  Category  
abc123   thriller  
abc123   horror  
def456   fiction  
def456   suspense  
def456   thriller  
pqr789   romance  
pqr789   fiction  
xyz123   thriller
```

ElementData

```
Element                     Match  
def456  
abc123  
xyz123  
pqr789
```

Comment: You can use `%in%` i.e. `as.integer(ElementData$Element %in% Catdata[,1])`

Comment: would this not return whether the element is present in categoryData$ElementID instead of checking whether the category matches with fiction, thriller or suspense?

Comment: I think i read the question incorrectly.  Possibly there is a solution posted which corrected that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `ElementData$Match` to return 1 if **any** value of `Catdata$category` for the corresponding value of `Catdata$Element` matches the criteria, you could do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
## Create lookup table of all elements matching the criteria:
matchData <- Catdata %>%
        group_by(Element) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(Match = (Category %in% 
                c("fiction", "suspense", "thriller")) %>% 
            any %>% as.integer)

## Merge your second table with the lookup table
ElementData <- ElementData %>% left_join(matchData, by = "Element")
```

Comment: You would just have to specify that name in the join, e.g., `ElementData <- ElementData %>% left_join(matchData, by = c("DataElement" = "Element"))`

Comment: Do you know how I can edit this to return 0.33 if one category matches, 0.66 if two match and 1 if all three match?

Comment: Solved using: 
        matchData <- Catdata %>%
        group_by(Element) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(Match = 0.33 *(3- sum(Category %in% 
                c("fiction", "suspense", "thriller"))) %>% 
            any %>% as.integer)